# C++ printing float as nan

Tags: c++, floating-point, nan

This is a simplified C++ program converting 4 bytes into their IEE754 float representation.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>

uint8_t bytes[4] = {0x40, 0xd5, 0xc6, 0x7f}; // 0x40d5c67f
float f;

int main()
{
    memcpy(&f, &bytes[0], 4);
    printf("%.*lf", 5, f);
}
```

it's output is `nan`! `isnan` also returns true for it. How has this happened? [0x40d5c67f is 6.6804...](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Happens both on my arduino-like microcontroller and http://cpp.sh/

Comment: What is your machine?

Comment: @MikeCAT good point, tested on an arduino-like microcontroller and http://cpp.sh/. Added to question.

Comment: Better ways to convert 4 bytes into a float also welcomed :)

Comment: What if you use `uint32_t bytes = UINT32_C(0x40d5c67f);` and `memcpy(&f, &bytes, 4);`?

Comment: @MikeCAT yeah that solves it! I'd love to know why though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running this code on a machine that uses **little-endian**,
higher digits of multi-byte numbers are stored in higher address of the memory.

Therefore, on little endian machines, the 4-byte number on memory
`0x40, 0xd5, 0xc6, 0x7f` is treated as `0x7fc6d540`, not `0x40d5c67f`.

Interpreting as IEEE754, the exponent part of this number is 255 and
the fraction part of this number is not 0, so this is NaN.